How to remove this old tub faucet?
I'm trying to remove this old tub faucet so I can replace it:

However, I can't tell how it's attached, and just twisting (as recommended in online videos) doesn't seem to be working; it doesn't want to move, and I'm worried about exerting too much force. (I'm not too worried about breaking the spout, since I'm replacing it anyway, but breaking the pipe would be very bad.)
I inspected the underside for a set screw, but, while there's a suspicious hole there, I don't see a screw:


How is this supposed to come off and/or how might one go about removing it?
(Note: I am aware there is still caulk around the spout, but there's a gap between the caulk and the spout, and when I twist it — gently! — the spout moves independent of the caulk, so that isn't the issue. I'll clean up the old caulk after the spout is off.)

From the Moen.com website:

I suspect the hole in the bottom of your spout is for water drainage to prevent flow into the wall.

Eh, no perfect answers and I don't feel like self-answering. I was eventually convinced to... be less squeamish about applying adequate force. The pipe doesn't seem to be rotating freely, so hopefully I didn't break anything inside the wall. For the record, the reason the pipe looks odd in the pictures is because it's off-white CPVC () with a bunch of crud on it.

How much have you twisted it?  It will probably require 2 to 4 turns. Put a mark on the pipe through the hole and turn the spout. Make sure the pipe isn't turning too.  If it is then there is another set of problems.
Consider cutting the spout about 5 inches from the wall.  You can then remove the pieces of the spout, but enough pipe will remain to be usable.
The pipe may be connected in the wall to a "Sharkbite" type fitting and it will turn. Your only option then is to replace the old spout with a "slip on" type that can be lubricated well and slid down the pipe.
The only other option is opening the wall behind the tub and examining and possibly replacing what is there.

It doesn't twist.

Then your options are: Use more force, ( be sure you are turning counter clockwise as if you were staring straight at it )  Or cut it.  It doesn't have the clamp, so it is screwed on, or someone glued it .
